# kivymd/uix/filemanager.py fails with module PIL not found

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I can find many questions related to the module PIL not found, with solutions. I tried many that I thought were applicable to me. BUt I still have no luck :(

My problem is this:
I have a project that shows current NAV of a portfolio using a KivyMD `MDDataTable`. The portfolio information is read from a PDF file using using `MDFileManager` and using tabula and panda, the file is parsed. Then market data is obtained from relevant markets and NAV is calculated. This then is displayed using `MDDatatable`. I am using python 3.8,  kivy 2.0.0rc4, and kivyMD  0.104.1. I can run this from the IDE and works beautifully. The problem is when running on my android phone
I use buildozer to create the apk file. The app starts, the splash screen is displayed and then it shuts off. logcat output shows this error which I believe is the reason as the first screen in the app uses filemanager( MDFileManager instance)

```
>     2020-10-24 13:13:54.517 24104-24183/? I/python:  Traceback (most recent call last):
>     2020-10-24 13:13:54.518 24104-24183/? I/python:    File "/home/tksrajan/dev/mark2market/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line
> 8, in <module>
>     2020-10-24 13:13:54.519 24104-24183/? I/python:    File "/home/tksrajan/dev/mark2market/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/mark2market/kivymd/uix/filemanager.py",
> line 119, in <module>
>     2020-10-24 13:13:54.520 24104-24183/? I/python:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
>     2020-10-24 13:13:54.520 24104-24183/? I/python: Python for android ended.
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is in the latest released version of kivyMD 0.104.1. The import of PIL in filemanager.py is superfluous and does nothing. You can fork the repo, remove the import and and use the modified repo. This solves the problem. The master branch of kivyMD has already removed this import. So next release will fix the problem permanently